# force matplotlibrc custom path

Tags: python, matplotlib, configuration-files

I have a custom `matplotlibrc` file stored on my computer, but with a custom name and not in the default `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` folder.

How can I indicate the path of this file to python, so matplotlib can use it ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question :

First, it is not exactly related about matplotlibrc, but about matplotlib *styles*. The slight difference between both is that matplotlibrc is oriented for the computer level, and a style is oriented for an user/project use.

Nevertheless, the syntax is the same for both files, except the `backend` option which has to be commented in the style file.

By convention, style file extension is `.mplstyle`.

To set a custom style file :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('file://' + mpl_style_file)
```

where `mpl_style_file` is the style file path.

The most important thing is this `file://` prefix

Comment: Why do you say that `file://` is important? As long as you point to the path of the `.mplstyle` file, there's no need to add anything else.